# Default value of uninitialized variable/object in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm new here. Just started learning Swift, and when I got to the topic of optionals, I started to wonder what the default value of an uninitialized variable is.

In Java, an 'int' gets initialized to 0. In C, it gets garbage value. So what's with Swift? To be a bit more precise, what is stored in x, when I write "var x: Int" ?

Also, if an uninitialized object "var c: UIColor" can not be pointing to nil, what does it point to?

Comment: If it's optional, the default value is `nil`. If not optional, it has no default value and must be initialized.

Comment: To answer your "precise" question...nothing is stored in x, when you write var x:Int. It is uninitialized (unlike Java/C# which implicitly initializes it to 0). You are just saying that you have a variable that can hold a specific datatype (Int in this case). You have to explicitly set its value before using it (or make it optional, in which case, it has a 'nil' value until initialized)

Comment: Thanks. It clearer to me now :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Non optionals

If you declare a variable like this

```
var color: UIColor
```

the state of the variable is `Uninitalized`. This means the compiler will not allow you to read it before it gets initialized.

```
print(color)
>> error: variable 'color' used before being initialized
```

### More

Interestingly the compiler is smart enough to check if all the branches of your code are initializing the variable before it gets used.

E.g. this code will produce an error because the compiler cannot guarantee that `color` is initialised before `print(color)` is executed.

```
var color: UIColor
let random = arc4random_uniform(10)
if random > 5 {
    color = UIColor.redColor()
}
print(color)
// error: variable 'color' used before being initialized
```

### Optionals

On the other hand if you declare a variable as an optional

```
var color: UIColor?
```

it gets initialised with `nil`

```
print(color)
// nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-optional variables don't have a default value.

You can't use uninitialized variables in Swift anyway. The compiler doesn't let you.